# Can you ever have a question mark after a full-stop/period?

Tags: punctuation

Can you ever have a question mark after a full-stop/period?

Imagine that Q.N. is the name of a secret society, and people just call it Q.N. Which one of the following is correct?

What time are you going to Q.N.?
What time are you going to Q.N?
I feel that the second is correct, but for some reason the first one is speaking to me as well. Any advice would be appreciated?

Comment: There's no period as far as the terminal punctuation is concerned: "Q.N." is a single entity and is to be treated as such, the periods are an integral part of the abbreviation. Ergo, you do need them before the question mark, or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not eliminate the period before a question mark. It doesn't make any sense to remove it in this instance.

Therefore, this is correct:

> "What time are you going to Q.N.?"

You, do, however, collapse periods at the end of a sentence: "I love the U.S.A." not "I love the U.S.A.."

I searched through my AP Stylebook for a reference, but I didn't find anything, so common sense rules.

Comment: "You, do, however, collapse periods at the end of a declarative/imperative sentence."